# Как сделать ActionBar на всю ширину экрана

Tags: android, java

Создаю кастомный ActionBar (sherlock), убираю иконку приложения и тайтл. Однако слева остается небольшой отступ. Как его можно убрать?

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
View customNav = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Все, вопрос решен)

Comment: @Anna1994, Если вы нашли ответ, опубликуйте его, он может помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: Мне помогло добавление строчки

getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");